# Powershell function would not break out of loop

Tags: .net, loops, powershell, for-loop, recursion

I have a powershell function that is supposed to return the next available node in a tree in a preorder fashion, basically a node that has not been traversed. However, what I have found is that the code would not exit out to the place where the function is called, instead, it returns to the foreach loop of the function and jumps to the next branch, I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
function Get-nextAvailable {
    param (
        $tree
    }

    $nextNode = $null
    foreach ($branch in $tree){
        if ($branch.traversal -eq $false){
            return $branch      
        }
        else {
            Get-nextAvailable ($branch.children)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking out of the most recent control element.

If you need to break out of a different one you can use labels. See `help about_break` for details.

As an aside: Why `break` there why not just return directly?

Also you aren't using the return value of the nested `Get-nextAvailable` call.

Comment: a return is doing the same thing, I want to return the variable and exit out the whole function, but it is continuing on to the next branch of the tree

Comment: `break` exits the inner-most loop. `return` exits the function. They cannot be doing the same thing. That being said, you are ignoring the return value from the nested call so if you ever hit that case you will walk the entire tree because you cannot exit until you do. So when `$branch.traversal` is `$true` you will never exit until you finish the entire walk.

Comment: is there a way to exit early? would adding a return after Get-nextAvailable ($branch.children) exit the function?

Comment: You need to do *something* with the return from the nested call if you expect to be able to have your function stop at that point. Then you also need to be able to pick up from where you left off the next time. How are you expecting this function to be used? How are you expecting this function to work?